# my single.php is mixup on some post for no reason

Tags: theme-development, css, html, single

some of my post is shown well(like http://exam.downloadkaran.com/?p=453) but another post is not shown well(like http://exam.downloadkaran.com/?p=258)!!! i don't know  exactly what should i have to search for. would u please to help me to find a clue. where to start to find my bug. i compare two file but find no mistake all div and other tag are closed well. 
in some post the problem is solved when i remove

```
 <?php the_tags(__(' ','dnld'), __(', ','dnld'), __('','dnld')); ?>
```

but in another one no. it is so complex situation!!!
my single.php is here:

```
                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/sevenmid.php"); ?>

        <div class="midpostbody post">
             <div class="postheader">
                    <a  href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
                </div><!--End post header-->

                <div class="view"><span><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) {   the_views(); } ?></span></div>
                <div class="category"><span><?php the_category(','); ?></span><a href="#">نرم افزار</a></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>    
            <div class="postimg"> <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ the_post_thumbnail();} else {?>
                <img  src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/Koala.jpg"  alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
              <?php }?>
              </div>
               <div class="customsize">
                <?php if(get_post_custom_values('sizelabel')) : ?>
                    <span><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sizelabel',true); ?>&nbsp;|</span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                   <?php if(get_post_custom_values('size')) : ?>
                    <span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'size',true); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
               </div>
               <div id="sincontent">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
               </div>
                <div id="postdata">
                    <div id="sharepic"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/sharep.png" alt="share here." /></div>
                    <div id="postsocial">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/cloob.png" alt="cloob" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/twitter.png" alt="cloob" /></a></li>                              <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="cloob" /></a></li>                             <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/google.png" alt="cloob" /></a></li>                               <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/technorati.png" alt="cloob" /></a></li>                               <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/delicious.png" alt="cloob" /></a></li>                                                            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/friendfeed.png" alt="cloob" /></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--End postsocial-->
                        <div id="tabs">
                            <ul>
                               <li> <a href="#tabs-3">لینک های دانلود</a></li> 
                                <li> <a href="#tabs-1">راهنمای دانلود</a></li>
                                <li> <a href="#tabs-2">راهنمای نصب</a></li>

                                <li> <a href="#tabs-4">مشخصات</a></li> 
                                <li> <a href="#tabs-5">سیستم مورد نیاز</a></li>                       
                            </ul>
                            <div id="tabs-1">
                            <p>
                      <?php if(get_post_custom_values('direct')) : ?>

                                <span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'size',true); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                                <span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'direct',true); ?></span>

                      <?php endif; ?>

                      <?php if(get_post_custom_values('link')) : ?>
                              <span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'linksize',true); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
                                <span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link',true); ?></span>

                      <?php endif; ?>
                                yes this is
                               <br />
                               <br />
                               and don't be affriad of them.!!!
                            </p>


                            </div>
                            <div id="tabs-2" style="display:none;"><p>
                            <?php if(get_post_custom_values('downguid')) : ?>
                                <p> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'downguid',true); ?></p>

                            <?php endif; ?>yes
                            </p></div>
                            <div id="tabs-3" style="display:none;"><p >
                            <?php if(get_post_custom_values('installguid')) : ?>
                                <span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'installguid',true); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>                                
                            </p></div>
                            <div id="tabs-4" style="display:none;"><p >
                            <?php if(get_post_custom_values('properties')) : ?>
                                <span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'properties',true); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>                                                                
                            </p></div>
                            <div id="tabs-5" style="display:none;">
                            <?php if(get_post_custom_values('requiresys')) : ?>
                                <span> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'requiresys',true); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>                                  
                            </div>

                     </div><!--End tab-->
                     <div id="errorpost">
                        <p>رمز کلیه فایل ها <strong>wwww.downloadkaran.com</strong>می باشد.</p>
                        <div><a>گزارش خرابی لینک</a></div>
                     </div><!--End error post-->
                </div><!--End postdata-->

                <div class="downsize"></div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="label">
                    <div>
                        <strong>برچسب ها:</strong>

                            <!--ُشروع-->
                <?php the_tags(__(' ','dnld'), __(', ','dnld'), __('','dnld')); ?>  
                                                    <!--ُپایان-->
                    </div>
                </div><!--end label-->
                <div class="clear"> </div>
                <div class="date"><span><?php the_time(__('j / F / Y','kubrick')) ?></span></div>
                <div class="comment"><?php comments_popup_link(__('&#1576;&#1583;&#1608;&#1606; &#1606;&#1592;&#1585;'), __('1 &#1606;&#1592;&#1585;'), __('% &#1606;&#1592;&#1585;')); ?></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!--End midpostbody post -->
            <!--Real Post section-->
         <?php
//for use in the loop, list 5 post titles related to first tag on current post
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {

$first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
$args=array(
'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=>5,
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {?>
             <div class="midpostbody post">
                <div class="postheader">
                    <a  >پست های مشابه</a>
                </div><!--End post header-->
 <div id="related">
<ul><?php
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to  <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a></li>
  <br />
<?php
endwhile;
}?>
    </ul>
     </div><!--End related section-->
                </div>
    <?php   wp_reset_query();
  }

  ?>
             <div id="shop" class="midpostbody">
                                    <div id="gallery-wrap">
                  <ul id="gallery">
                 <?php  $tmp_query = new WP_Query('cat='.get_cat_ID('فروشگاه'));
                     while ( $tmp_query->have_posts() ) : $tmp_query->the_post();?>
                         <li>
                             <?php the_post_thumbnail();?> 
                            <br />
                             <h2>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                             </h2>
                             <div><a href="#">خرید پستی</a></div>
                         </li>
                     <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                  </ul><!--End gallary ul-->
                  </div><!--End gallery-wrap-->

                  <div id="gallery-controls">
                   <a href="#" id="gallery-next"></a>
                    <a href="#" id="gallery-prev"></a>

                </div><!--End gallery controls-->
             </div><!--End shop-->
             <div id="signin" class="midpostbody">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/group-poste-sabet.jpg" alt="عضویت در آرمان" />
                <h3>
                    مزیت های عضویت در آرمان دانلود :
                </h3>
                <ul>
                    <li> » دریافت آخرین مطالب جذاب منتشر شده در سایت</li>
                    <li> » مشاهده آخرین مطالب خواندنی و جذاب منتشر شده در انجمن</li>
                    <li>» دریافت آخرین عکس های اضافه شده به گالری عکس پس زمینه</li>
                    <li> » ارسال مطالب تاثیر گذار و متفاوت از سراسر دنیای وب فارسی و انگلیسی</li>
                    <li>» هر هفته منتظر طالع خودتان باشید و آن را در ایمیل تان مشاهده کنید</li>
                    <li> » اطلاع از جذاب ترین مطالب شبکه های اجتماعی و سایت های خبری</li>
                    <li>» دریافت آخرین مطالب و عکس های مد و فشن ایرانی و خارجی</li>
                    <li>» جدیدترین فیلم ها و عکس های منتشر شده در دنیای اینترنت</li>
                    <li> » آخرین خبرهای هنری و اقتصادی و تکنولوژی….</li>
                    <li>» و در انتها پیشنهاد های ویژه ما که فقط مخصوص اعضا می باشد  </li>
                </ul>
                <div><a href="#"></a></div>
             </div><!--ٍEnd signin Section-->
             <div>
                <?php?>
             </div>
                 <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/comments.php"); ?>
   </div><!--End midpannel--> 

            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/sidebar-left.php"); ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div id="bottom" ></div><!--End bottom section-->
    </div><!--End content section-->
            </div><!--End outer section-->
            <?php 
            wp_footer();
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . "/footer.php");
             ?>
```

Comment: Please describe what, exactly, isn't displaying properly: what do you *expect* to see, and don't see - or what do you see *unexpectedly*?

Answer (score 1):

I would check the post content of the post that is not shown well for unclosed or unopened `<div>`, `<span>`, whatever elements. If you are using Firefox, CMD+U (or Ctrl+U) will show you the source code that - for example - shows unopened but closed `<a>` and `<p>` tags in lines 853, 878... also w3c validation would be a good idea.

But, please... nothing happens "for no reason"... ;)